# Closure - Timing of deinit self object

Tags: swift, closures

```
class Increment {
   var number = 0
 
   init(){
       print(#function)
    }
   deinit {
       print(#function)
   }
   //    let incrementNumber would give an error — 1
   lazy var incrementNumber: (Int) -> () = { [weak self] value in
       self?.number += value
       print(self?.number)
   }
}
 
do {
   let increment = Increment().incrementNumber(3)
}
// output
init()
deinit
nil
```

if I separate the line, `self` is still alive when the closure is executed.

```
let increment = Increment()
increment.incrementNumber(3)
// output
init()
Optional(3)
deinit
```

Can anyone please explain why the `Increment` get deinit before the `incrementNumber()` call?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all you need to know definition of lazy variable.

> According to [apple docs](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/LanguageGuide/Properties.html), A lazy stored property is a property whose initial value isn’t calculated until the first time it’s used. You indicate a lazy stored property by writing the lazy modifier before its declaration.

Means that when the class is initial, they don't know they have variable lazy inside which is `incrementNumber`.

That the reason when you call

```swift
do {
   let increment = Increment().incrementNumber(3)
}
```

`Increment` don't recognized `incrementNumber` in the class when you access directly. So Swift only see that you do nothing with `Increment` class in the rest of code then it automatically `deinit` the unused class.

**Update**: As Mr. DuncanC's mentioned, because of `deinit` class first so the compiler create an instance of `Increment` as AutoReleased, and keep it in memory in order to evaluate the second part of the expression

At the second, you call

```swift
let increment = Increment()
increment.incrementNumber(3)
```

Means that you make a class at first then you make lazy variable ( Swift sees that you do something with that class in second line so it waits until everything in class is called). Then in the rest of code class `Increment` is unused then it automatically `deinit`. That's the reason you see lazy is call before `deinit`.

For more further knowledge, you can do like making a `not lazy function` to see the difference.

```swift
class Increment {
   var number = 0

   init(){
       print(#function)
    }

   deinit {
       print(#function)
   }

    public func increaseNumber(_ value: Int) {
        self.number += value
        print(#function)
    }
}

do {
    let increment = Increment().increaseNumber(3)
}

//init()
//increaseNumber(_:)
//deinit
```

As you can see that `increaseNumber` is called before `deinit` because the class know that it owns func `increaseNumber` so it was called. Then in the rest of code class `Increment` is unused then it automatically `deinit`.

Comment: This doesn't really answer the question for me. In the expression `Increment().incrementNumber(3)` I would expect the compiler to create an instance of Increment as AutoReleased, and keep it in memory in order to evaluate the second part of the expression.

Comment: Dear @DuncanC, I see it still creating an instance after all with ``nil`` self because the class is already ``deinit``. So thank you for your comment. I've updated my answer.